# iOS storyboards do not support target device type "watch"

Tags: xcode7, watchos-2

I am using Xcode 7.2, WatchOS 2.1.
I have below problem

```
Base.lproj/Main.storyboard: iOS storyboards do not support target device type "watch".
```

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Open the file inspector for your storyboard file and make sure that on the `Target Memberships` list the watch app & extension are NOT selected

Answer (score 7):

In addition to target memberships, and especially when working with a single target that supports multiple platforms (ex. iOS and tvOS), you can more-deeply customize the build by clicking on the project in the sidebar then going into the target, selecting "Build Phases" and then using the "Filters" column.

By default, files are listed as "Always Used", but you can limit to specific platforms as needed in this way, even as part of a single target.

*It would be nice if these same settings were exposed in the inspector as well since this feels pretty hidden, but this is how it is as of Xcode 14.1 at least.*

Comment: This is the only solution for projects that have both iOS and tvOS in a single target (you cannot uncheck a resource without having multiple targets).

Answer (score 5):

I just crossed the same problem. I did:

1. Click on the warning
2. On the right side select the "File Inspector"
3. Go down to the "Target Membership"
4. Unselect the "main app"

This worked for me.
Cheers.

Comment: Actually for me, I had to remove the xib for the watchkit app and watchkit extension. But yes that was great information!